# Is there a way to make Putty use the standard copy/paste keys

Tags: putty, clipboard

It's ridiculous Putty has always used a non-standard way to copy/paste. Is there a way to use Ctrl-c to copy and Ctrl-v to paste?

Comment: Ctrl-c in UNIX/Linux send signal to the current running process (in frontend). Is it so heavy to use Ctrl+Ins?

Answer (score 13):

The author of PuTTY, Simon Tatham, addressed this to some extent in more recent versions. Certainly in Version 0.71 you can configure **Ctrl+Shift+C/V** to behave as **Ctrl+C/V**, which is much closer than the Ctrl/Shift+Ins that was originally available.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Nope, no way!

Take a look at [Using PuTTY](http://the.earth.li/~sgtatham/putty/0.52/htmldoc/Chapter3.html#3.1.1):

> PuTTY's copy and paste works entirely with the mouse. In order to copy
>   text to the clipboard, you just click the left mouse button in the
>   terminal window, and drag to select text. When you let go of the
>   button, the text is automatically copied to the clipboard. You do not
>   need to press Ctrl-C or Ctrl-Ins; in fact, if you do press Ctrl-C,
>   PuTTY will send a Ctrl-C character down your session to the server
>   where it will probably cause a process to be interrupted.

Comment: That is a shame that is not an option - and I know how it works. I've been using putty off and on for a long time and the non-standard copy/paste has always bugged me. The rest of the (windows) world uses the standard copy paste and I end up right clicking in another application to paste and vise-versa. Yes, I understand about sending the ctrl-c to the session. I prefer the mac where command-c/command-v doesn't mess with the session. Thanks for your feedback.

Comment: You are welcome, Bruce! Don't hesitate to mark the answer as accepted if you fill so, not only this one but generally :)

Answer (score 2):

You can install [AutoHotkey](https://autohotkey.com/download/) and then use this code in your ahk-script:

```
#IfWinActive, ahk_class PuTTY
^v::
MouseClick, right
Send, {DOWN}{ENTER}
Return
#IfWinActive
```

The right mouse button will be pressed, but because you pressed Ctrl+V, it is handled as Ctrl+MouseRight, which will bring up the context menu. Pressing down arrow will navigate to the "Paste" option; enter will execute paste.

Answer (score 0):

Supplement @Kees' answer

`Putty Reconfiguration` - `Window` - `Selection` - `Action of mouse buttons:` - check `Windows (Midd...)`

```
;--- PuTTY
#IfWinActive ahk_exe putty.exe

^v::
Send +{Insert}
return
```

Answer (score 0):

I tried @Gavin Jackson and @kees answers but they didn't work for me (putty 0.76).
I went with this [AHK](https://autohotkey.com/download/) :

```
#If WinActive("ahk_class PuTTY")
^c::
    MouseClick, right
    Send, {DOWN}{ENTER}
Return
^v::
    MouseClick, right
    Send, {DOWN}{DOWN}{ENTER}
Return
#IfWinActive
```

With this configuration:

[image]